# Okta 'request body was not well-formed' during very simple property update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, okta

I am calling the okta API from my .Net back-end. It works fine when creating the user (the first part of the snippet below), so I know the token is correct etc. and I can confirm the new user exists.

I also, subsequently, update a property I've added to the user called 'Site'. When attempting to assign this property a value it throws an exception on the 'UpdateAsync' line that the request body was not well formed

```
            var user = await _oktaClient.Users.CreateUserAsync(new CreateUserWithPasswordOptions
            {
                Profile = new UserProfile
                {
                    FirstName = value.FirstName,
                    LastName = value.Surname,
                    Email = value.Email,
                    Login = value.Email,
                },
                Password = value.Password,
                Activate = true,
            });

            var newUser = await _oktaClient.Users.GetUserAsync(user.Id);

            newUser["site"] = Site;
            await newUser.UpdateAsync(); // This line throws!
```

Note: I wasn't always doing it this way, I was previously assigning to the `user` object and then calling `UpdateAsync()` once I'd updated 'site' on the user object. This is an alternative approach as I'm trying different things (i.e. getting the user from the API again). Neither approach works.

What's very strange is that this has been working, I am 100% certain of that. I'm looking through my okta users directory 'as we speak', and there are a load of users, all with their site property populated. There has been no problem previously. I believe something must've been updated okta's end that now doesn't like my request for some reason but in either case I need a work-around ideally.

I can confirm `Site` is neither null or empty, it's simply a string.

### UPDATE

I just discovered a `SetProperty` extension on okta's `IResource`, calling this before attempting to update the user causes the same issue.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting same error via Postman?

Comment: Aren't custom attributes usually added to the users profile `newUser.Profile["site"] = Site;`?

Comment: Ah that would make sense, thanks @Yosh. What would't make sense is how it has worked previously!? I will test this when I'm home.

Comment: I just took a brief glance at the source, seems like the User class inherited from Resource in the past. This could be the reason it previously worked...

Comment: @Yosh - thanks a lot for your efforts, really appreciate it. Can you post this as the answer please? Disappointed to see a breaking change was made without a head's up from Okta but nothing I can do I suppose.

Comment: @JayMee, you're welcome! So it's working this way?!

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly. And you've saved me a massive headache! I am using Okta for multitenancy. I'm assigning the 'site' property to the profile to determine which tenant the user belongs to. So you've just allowed me to implement that end to end. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like custom attributes can't be assigned to the User object itself anymore, but need to be in the users profile: `newUser.Profile["site"] = Site;`